# Distinguish android onStart function in different cases(Rotate or create new activity)

Tags: android, rotation, onstart

I find three cases which will call Android activity `onStart()` function:

1. Create a new activity, `onStart()` will follow behind onCreate
2. Press home button bring activity background and then bring it forward, it will also call `onStart()`, and it will follow behind `onRestart()`.
3. Rotate the screen, the activity will `onPause()`, `onStop()`, `onDestroy()` and then `onCreate()` and `onStart()` again.

I want to do some actions in `onStart()` function in case1 while not do it in case2 or case3, anyone knows how to do it? Any help is appreciated! Thank you！

Comment: so you want to do some actions only once in the entire lifespan of your activity?

Comment: Yes! I find that in onCreate I can detect the bundle is null or not. but it is a not direct way.

Comment: just use some static boolean flag to indicate if to do your action or not

Comment: I find a way is detect whether the parameter in onCreate is null.